# Npm build version text looks different

Tags: npm

[Login page text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sClZ6.png)

As the title suggests, after running npm run build, everything style wise looks identical except for the text. I'm currently using react bootstrap. The image link above shows the login page for my test version (left) vs. build version (right).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Was using a bootswatch theme and the font didn't seem to translate to build. Changed the font manually on index.html